# For discord python, How do I print a message every x seconds with task?

Tags: python, discord.py

E.g I'm trying to write hello in general chat every 10 seconds. How do I do that? I'm using the task feature.

```
channel = client.get_channel('channel id') 
@tasks.loop(seconds=10)
async def sendmessage():
    await channel.send("hello")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Start the task with `.start()

```
channel = client.get_channel('channel id') 
@tasks.loop(seconds=10)
async def sendmessage():
    await channel.send("hello")

sendmessage.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your "channel id" is an integer, and your code should work as is, assuming you have `sendmessage.start()` somewhere.

An extra note: you probably want to put your `get_channel` inside your task. `get_channel` gets the channel object from the internal cache, so if the cache expires your channel object will too.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try moving channel into the function, like this:

```py
import discord
import datetime
from discord.ext import commands, tasks

TOKEN = 'token'

client = discord.Client()

@tasks.loop(seconds=10)
async def sendmessage():
     channel = client.get_channel('channel id')
     await channel.send("hello")

sendmessage.start()


client.run(TOKEN)
```

The `get_channel` function only takes integer as input.

Answer (score 0):

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks

bot = commands.Bot('!') # ! = PREFIX

@tasks.loop(seconds=10)
async def sendmessage():
     channel = bot.get_channel(123456789) #Channel ID
     await channel.send("hello")

sendmessage.start()
bot.run("TOKEN")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `sendmessage.start` on your `on_ready` event.

Example:

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    sendmessage.start()
```